# Adding an extra value into CSV data, according to filename

Tags: shell, csv, awk, cat

Let's say i have the following type of filename formats : 
`CO#ATH2000.dat` , `CO#MAR2000.dat`

Each of these, have data like that following:

```
....   
"12-02-1984",3.8,4.1,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.7,4.1,4.3,3.8,4.1,5.0,4.8,4.5,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.1,4.5,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.5,4.3,4.1
"13-02-1984",3.7,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.1,4.3,4.5,4.8,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.0,5.2,5.2,5.2,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.5,4.3
"14-02-1984",3.8,4.1,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,4.2,4.5,4.5,4.1,3.6,3.6,3.4,3.4,3.2,3.4,3.2,3.2,3.2,2.9,2.7,2.5,2.2
"15-02-1984",2.2,2.2,2.0,2.0,2.0,1.8,2.1,2.6,2.6,2.5,2.4,2.4,2.4,2.5,2.7,2.7,2.6,2.6,2.7,2.6,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8
..........
```

Now i also have the following `.sh` file that can merge ALL those `.dat` files into one single output `.dat` file.

```
for filename in `ls CO#*`; do
    cat $filename >> CO#combined.dat
done
```

Now here is the problem. I want inside `CO#combined.dat`, at each line, before the start of the values, to have a 'standard' value according to the `filename`-parameter. For example i want each file with `ATH` in its filename have `3,` at the start of each line and with `MAR` in its filename have `22,`.

So the `CO#combined.dat` should be something like this:

```
....   
3,"12-02-1984",3.8,4.1,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.7,4.1,4.3,3.8,4.1,5.0,4.8,4.5,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.1,4.5,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.5,4.3,4.1
3,"13-02-1984",3.7,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.1,4.3,4.5,4.8,4.8,5.0,5.2,5.0,5.2,5.2,5.2,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.5,4.3
20,"14-02-1984",3.8,4.1,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,4.2,4.5,4.5,4.1,3.6,3.6,3.4,3.4,3.2,3.4,3.2,3.2,3.2,2.9,2.7,2.5,2.2
20,"15-02-1984",2.2,2.2,2.0,2.0,2.0,1.8,2.1,2.6,2.6,2.5,2.4,2.4,2.4,2.5,2.7,2.7,2.6,2.6,2.7,2.6,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8
..........
```

So in conclusion i want the script to do the above procedure!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk you can take advantage of the built-in `FILENAME` variable along with the fact that you can supply multiple files to a given invocation. awk processes each file in turn, setting `FILENAME` to the name of the file whose records are currently being read.

With that you can set your prefix according to whatever pattern you wish to search for in the file name. Finally you can print the prefix and the original record.

Here's a demonstration on simplified versions of your sample input:

```
$ cat CO\#ATH2000.dat 
1
2
3

$ cat CO\#MAR2000.dat
A
B
C

$ awk 'FILENAME ~ /MAR/ {pre=22} FILENAME ~ /ATH/ {pre=3} { print pre "," $0 }' CO*.dat
3,1
3,2
3,3
22,A
22,B
22,C
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Works like a charm! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

can be done simply

```
for f in CO#*; do 
      case ${f:3:3} in 
          ATH) k=3 ;; 
          *) k=22 ;; 
      esac; 
      sed "s/^/$k,/" $f >> all; 
done
```

${f:3:3} extract the code ATH or MAR from the filename it's bash substring function; case converts the code to numerical counterpart; sed insert the numerical value and comma at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Very nice. I would write: `case $f in *ATH*) ...` to meet the "each file with ATH in its filename" requirement.

Comment: @sarriman, note that you should **not** iterate over `ls`, as karakfa illustrates -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: i dont understant completly this code i think... what `case ${f:3:3}` does...? and also what `sed` does..